# Strange alignment behaviour in UIImageView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am having difficulty trying to get a proper alignment of a `UIImageView`.

Right now, I have a very simple storyboard with just a UIButton and UIImageView in a single view (see attached image).

An outlet has been set in the controller:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewer;
```

For the `UIImageView`, view mode is set to `Aspect Fit`. The edges of the `UIImageView` are aligned to the edges of the `ViewController`. When the `UIButton` is clicked, it will trigger update the `UIImageView` with an image:

```
@synthesize imageViewer;
- (IBAction)submitPressed:(id)sender {

   ... //url declared in this hidden chunk

   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
   imageViewer.image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];
}
```

[image]

As you can see, there is a margin on the left for some reason and although the `UIImageView` has been set to `Aspect Fit`, cropping occurred on the right edge of the image (red portion has been cropped away).

I tried putting normal margins on all sides and the image was cropped even more on the right. I considered that it may be an issue with the `NSData` and tried to load the remote image directly in a `UIWebView` and the issue remains.

Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you in advance.

Comment: are you using autolayout?

Comment: Did you try using constraints? Apply constraints **Leading Space to Superview** and **Trailing Space to Superview** and set constant to **0**

Comment: Hmm i don't see these constraint options. let me look again

Comment: Select the **UIImageView** in your **NIB**, then click on **Editor > Pin > Leading Space to Superview**. Then in the **Attribute Inspector** set **Constant** to **0**. Do the same and apply **Trainling Space to SuperView**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply **Constraints** to your **UIImageView**.

Select the **UIImageView** in your **NIB**, then click on **Editor > Pin > Leading Space to Superview**. Then in the **Attribute Inspector** set **Constant** to **0**. Do the same and apply **Trainling Space to SuperView**.